# Howto trace this bitmap?

Tags: inkscape

I have a fairly blurry image, which supposed to be easily redrawn:

[image]

However, when I choose trace from menu, it gets me very complicated results, and I wish to avoid freehanded redrawing.

Here is my result with auto-trace:

[image]

Middle circle is not needed, as it's a perfect circle, it's easy to redraw.

But how could I redraw the cogs of the gear to be perfectly symmetric in every direction?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but please don't disparage downvoters here.  People are free to downvote if they think there is something wrong with a question, specifically if  the question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". A little harsh perhaps, but I've answered the question anyway. At least I think it's useful. ;)

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr: your answer is indeed very useful, I'm doing it right now, and wish to accept after finishing (but it seems very thorough). My comment about the downvote might seem a bit cynicism, but I think when someone downvotes something, she/he shall add some comment on how could I improve the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raster image is too low quality for a good auto trace. Unless you have something better, it would simply be easier to redraw it. Garbage in = garbage out.

Redrawing is fairly simple. Here are the basic steps for one method.

1. Just draw one half of a cog tooth, with a little overlap over the centre line to ensure no gaps during rotation
2. Round some corners using the Corners LPE, and then rotate and mirror copies using the Rotate Copies LPE (see settings shown below), and move the rotate origin to your guides.
3. Do *Path > Object to Path*, add a stroke, no fill. Draw a circle in the middle

[image]Click to see larger